# Is there a simpler method to set height of UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

To set height of `UIView`, I need to set frame to its x, y, width and finally my height.

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, myHeight)]
```

which is pretty annoying. Is there a simpler build-in way?

Answer (score 7):

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.size.height = myHeight;
view.frame = frame;
```

which is smaller and also conveys only the meaning you require (that you change the height and nothing else)

Answer (score 2):

```
#define SetViewHeight(view, height) [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)]
```

now you can use `SetViewHeight(view, myHeight);` to set height.

Answer (score 2):

YES! Make a Category on UIVIew

```
@interface UIView (Customize)

- (void)setX:(CGFloat)x;
- (void)setY:(CGFloat)y;
- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width;
- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height;

@end

@implementation

- (void)setX:(CGFloat)x
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x = x;
    self.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setY:(CGFloat)y
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y = y;
    self.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.width = width;
    self.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

Import your category where you want and just call on your view:

```
[view setHeight:666];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just going to have to build your frame and set it like that. Or you can create a category to accomplish custom helper methods.